# Finding lowest element in every row of a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested list which looks like this.

```
[[0.0, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979],
 [1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.0],
 [2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 1.0],
 [2.23606797749979, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
```

I want to find the minimum element in every sub list. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Honestly I tried googling this answer before before posting. I am not sure why people are giving negative feedback to the question. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @AshleyLarson Surely you have tried something?

Comment: All your numbers are square roots of integers, the main diagonal is all zeros, and the matrix is symmetric. Why? What problem are you really solving? [**XY Problem**](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I am trying to solve the travelling salesman problem. The nested list is the distance matrix for 4 different cities. So choosing zeros would not make sense. So I replaced all the zeros by a very high number and now the next problem I am stuck is about not repeating the indexes.

Comment: How large can the number of cities become?

Comment: I am trying to solve for cities less than 40.

Comment: @AshleyLarson The "negative" feedback you are getting is really reinforcement feedback. If you were doing work for an instructor, the instructor would ask you the same things we are "What have you tried so far?". Their role is not to give you an answer, but further enhance your understanding of the material; for that they need to know how far along you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well because others are already posting answers, you can store the minimum value of each sublist in a list using what is called *list comprehension* like so:

`new_s = [min(x) for x in s]`

Python has a built-in `min()` function that takes an iterable (i.e. one of your sublists) and finds the minimum value. By using *list comprehension* you build a list of those values. It can be read as:

"A list of minimum values for each x (sublist) in s (parent list)"

**Edit:** For commented use:

`new_s = [sorted(x)[1] for x in s]`

Can be read as:

"A list of the 2nd element in the sorted array of x for each x (sublist) in s (parent list)"

Comment: If I need not the lowest element but the second lowest element. I tried something like new_s=[min(x) for x in s if min(x)>0] but it gave the same answer.

Comment: @AshleyLarson Please see my edit. However, you really should have updated your question if your true goal was to get the 2nd to lowest, not the lowest.

Comment: I replaced all the zeros with a very large number and used your method then. It worked fine.

Comment: @AshleyLarson But do you understand what has happened. That is more important than "it worked fine"

Comment: Yep you created a sorted list and then chose the element with index 1. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @AshleyLarson I cant, simply because I didnt give you any. It seems all you did was upvote. Can you click the "checkmark" on the side, it marks this as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`, which is slightly more efficient than list comprehension when utilizing a builtin function, in this case `min`:

```
s = [[0.0, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979],
[1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.0],
[2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 1.0],
[2.23606797749979, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
new_s = list(map(min, s))
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

An alternative list comprehension as @pstatix mentioned:

```
new_s = [min(i) for i in s]
```

Comment: That does not output that. In fact, `new_s` will store a `map` object. You have to convert the `map` to a `list` by setting `new_s = list(map(min, s))`.

Comment: Better yet is list comprehension: `new_s = [min(x) for x in s]`

Comment: It's self explanatory, isn't it?

Comment: For something as simple as this, both are pythonic solutions.

Comment: @StefanPochmann one would declare an empty list, and then followed by a for loop and a operation to append to that list with `min()` or do the stuff within the `[]` which increases the readability, I'd choose latter ,for you i don't know.